# How to determine two matrices are conjugate.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Which of the following statements are true?

- The matrices $
    A=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
     1 & 1 \\
     0 & 1\\
    \end{array} } \right]$ and $
    B=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
     1 & 0 \\
     1 & 1\\
    \end{array} } \right]$ are conjugate in $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$
- The matrices $
    A=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
     1 & 1 \\
     0 & 1\\
    \end{array} } \right]$ and $
    B=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
     1 & 0 \\
     1 & 1\\
    \end{array} } \right]$ are conjugate in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$
- The matrices $
    C=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
     1 & 0 \\
     0 & 2\\
    \end{array} } \right]$ and $
    D=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
     1 & 3 \\
     0 & 2\\
    \end{array} } \right]$ are conjugate in $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$

I know the conjugate matrices have the same eigenvalues. But all of this matrices have the same eigenvalues. I am not sure how to determine that which matrices are conjugate to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Quiver has already told you (and I am sure it is in you textbook) that two matrices, A and B, are conjugate if and only if there exist an invertible matrix, P, such that $A= P^{-1}BP$.  That is equivalent to $PA= BP$.

In the first problem, $A= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.  We can show they are conjugate by finding an appropriate P!

Since A and B are 2 by 2 P must be also and we can write it $\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ so we must have
$\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$$\iff$
$\begin{bmatrix}a & a+ b\\ c & c+ d\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ a+ c & b+ d\end{bmatrix}$.

We must have a= a, a+ b= b, c= a+ c, and c+ d= c+ d.
Both a+ b= b and c= a+ c reduce to a= 0 while c+ c= c+ d is always true.
Any matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix}0 & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ will do.

Answer (score 0):

### Hint

> The definition of conjugacy is: if $A$ and $B$ are two matrices such that $$A= P^{-1}BP$$ then they are conjugate. In $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is the same as similarity so not only the eigenvalues have to be preserved: mainly two similar matrices in $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ have the same *Jordan normal form*.

Notice that $A$ is in Jordan canonical form (just look at the eigenvalues). Notice that the matrix $D$ is diagonalisable.

Probabily [this forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625628) can help for the second question.

Comment: What is $D$ here?

Comment: Sorry, I'm indicating the matrices as they are on your worksheet $$ A=\left[\begin{matrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]$$ and $$ D=\left[\begin{matrix} 1&3\\0&2\end{matrix}\right]$$