# Name for matrix operation that inverses off-diagonal elements

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, inverse, symmetry

Is there any operation that sends matrix
$$
S=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a&b\\
c& d
\end{array}\right) \to S' 
=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \:\:\:a&-b\\
-c& \:\:\:d
\end{array}\right)
\quad a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}
$$
by setting off-diagonal elements of 2x2 matrix to inverse?
My question is: is there a name (or notation) for this kind of matrix operation?

If I would assume that $b,c \in Im$ (imaginary) then the operation obviously can be defined as conjugate $S'=(S^*)^T$. But all values are real in the given case.

Edit: $S \in SL(2, \mathbb{R}) $

Comment: $Im$ is an imaginary value $i b$.

Comment: Since the only real number $b$ with $b=-\overline{b}$ is $b=0$, the map $S\mapsto (S^*)^T$ then only coincides with your map for $b=c=0$, i.e., for diagonal matrices, where it is just the identity.

Comment: No, $a,b,c,d$ are all real in my case. I said IFF b,c are imaginary the answer is trivial. And this is matrix conjugate.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I just reformulated this. So for real entries, this has nothing interesting to do with transpose, or conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 1):

The two matrices $S$ and $S'$ are [*conjugate*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860140/how-to-determine-two-matrices-are-conjugate), or [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14075/how-do-i-tell-if-matrices-are-similar%5D) since they have the same characteristic polynomial
$$
t^2-(a+d)t+(ad-bc),
$$
provided that they aren't a scalar multiple of the identity, i.e., provided that $(b,c)\neq (0,0)$.

Comment: In my case matrix S transforms vectors $V'= S V S^T$. However, in one specific case, I need to have $V'= S V S' $ to build a homomorphic map. Your answer means that there is no such way, so I have to work out conjugation.

Comment: Conjugation is a great idea! I think that's it.

Comment: Though I do not see yet P such as $S'= P^{-1}S P$. At least for $a,b,c, d  \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I had something in mind if b,c are imaginary $$
S'=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \sqrt{i}&0\\
0& \sqrt{-i}
\end{array}\right) 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} a&b\\
c& d
\end{array}\right) 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} \sqrt{-i}&0\\
0& \sqrt{i}
\end{array}\right) =
\left(\begin{array}{cc} a&ib\\
-ic& d
\end{array}\right) 
$$ I doubt it can be done for reals.But I wait..

Comment: I have found such a $P$. But I assumed that you want real entries, as above. In fact, assuming $b\neq 0$ we have $S'=P^{-1}SP$ for any matrix 
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix} m_1 & m_2 \cr 
-\frac{c}{b}m_2 & -m_1+\frac{d-a}{b}m_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with nonzero determinant. For example let $m_1$ be a solution of the quadratic equation
$$
b m_1^2 + m_1m_2( a - d) + b - cm_2^2=0.
$$

Comment: Yes, reals are good as I work in SL(2,R). But it seems it has an isomorphic map to a subgroup of SL(2,C).

Comment: You should have said before in the post that you assume $ad-bc=1$, i.e., $SL_2(\Bbb R)$. Then things get easier. Or do you mean $P\in SL_2(\Bbb R)$? That's what I did already with the quadratic equation in $m_1$.

Comment: Dietrich, thank you!

Comment: Yes, it was forgotten, det(S)=1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117129/discussion-between-eddward-and-dietrich-burde).

Answer (score 0):

Let me post my own answer.

Let $S \in \mathrm{SL(2,\mathbb{R}})$, and let C be a group of matrices with two imaginary off-diagonal elements- a subgroup of $\mathrm{SL(2,\mathbb{C}})$.
Since the S can be isomorphically mapped to some element $A \in C$ using the map
$S \to \mathrm{A=T S T^{-1}}$ as following
$$
S \to A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \sqrt{i}&0\\ 0& \sqrt{-i} \end{array}\right)  \left(\begin{array}{cc} a&b\\ c& d \end{array}\right)  \left(\begin{array}{cc} \sqrt{-i}&0\\ 0& \sqrt{i} \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \:\:\:a&ib\\ -ic& d \end{array}\right)
$$
(it is easy to see that the map is bijective, multiplicative e t c and the isomorphism).

Then after conjugating $A \to A^*$, the inverse map $\mathrm{T^{-1} (A^*) T }$ sends $A^*$ to
$$
S'=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \sqrt{-i}&0\\ 0& \sqrt{i} \end{array}\right)  \left(\begin{array}{cc} a& -ib\\ ic& \:\:\:d \end{array}\right)  \left(\begin{array}{cc} \sqrt{i}&0\\ 0& \sqrt{-i} \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \:\:\:a&-b\\ -c& \:\:\:d \end{array}\right)
$$
The operation is thereby is complex conjugation in the isomorphic group C (a subgroup of $\mathrm{SL(2,\mathbb{C}}$) with two imaginary off-diagonal elements). And since it is conjugation in the isomorphic group it is the conjugation.

PS. The same is valid for the conjugate transpose (or Hermitian transpose).